# System permission dialog is not centered

Tags: android, kotlin, permissions, dialog

I have a minor issue, the permission dialog that pops up to request the user's consent is not centered in the middle of the screen when I run the app on My Samsung Galaxy Tab A8.

[image]

While it's centered as expected when I run the app on Android Studio's emulator.

[image]

Did anyone face this issue?

Comment: Have you try other application permission if its coming same way like your app have than its fine its system default permission we cant change and edit it